# Authentication error when using rundeck cli (aka rd)

Tags: rundeck

I'm using `rundeck-cli` rd on my container. 
I set

```
RD_URL=http://localhost:4440/rundeck
RD_USER=myuser
RD_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

but

when trying to login, I fail to authenticate.
I tested the credentials on the web UI successfully

```
Apr 28, 2020 7:26:41 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: --> GET http://localhost:4440/rundeck/ http/1.1
Apr 28, 2020 7:26:41 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: <-- 302 Found http://localhost:4440/rundeck/ (8ms, 0-byte body)
Apr 28, 2020 7:26:41 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: --> GET http://localhost:4440/user/login http/1.1
Apr 28, 2020 7:26:41 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: <-- 200 OK http://localhost:4440/user/login (19ms, unknown-length body)
Apr 28, 2020 7:26:41 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: --> POST http://localhost:4440/rundeck/j_security_check http/1.1 (33-byte body)
Apr 28, 2020 7:26:41 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: <-- 302 Found http://localhost:4440/rundeck/j_security_check (26ms, 0-byte body)
Apr 28, 2020 7:26:41 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: --> GET http://localhost:4440/rundeck/ http/1.1
Apr 28, 2020 7:26:41 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: <-- 404 Not Found http://localhost:4440/rundeck/ (19ms, unknown-length body)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Password Authentication failed, expected a successful response.
        at org.rundeck.client.util.FormAuthInterceptor.authenticate(FormAuthInterceptor.java:82)
        at org.rundeck.client.util.FormAuthInterceptor.intercept(FormAuthInterceptor.java:59)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:229)
```

Comment: Do you have RD-CLI in the same container? Can you share your Dockerfile/docker-compose file?

Comment: I installed rundeck cli on the same container.
source [https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck-cli]
I also tried installing it on external container with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that "tuning" the Rundeck official image using docker-compose and Dockerfile.

Create a directory and put the `docker-compose.yml` with the following content:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  rundeck:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        IMAGE: ${RUNDECK_IMAGE:-rundeck/rundeck:3.2.6}
    ports:
      - 4440:4440
    links:
      - postgres
    environment:
      RUNDECK_DATABASE_DRIVER: org.postgresql.Driver
      RUNDECK_DATABASE_USERNAME: rundeck
      RUNDECK_DATABASE_PASSWORD: rundeck
      RUNDECK_DATABASE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres/rundeck?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
  postgres:
      image: postgres
      expose:
        - 3306
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=rundeck
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=rundeck
      volumes:
        - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
    dbdata:
```

And put this Dockerfile in the same directory with the following content:

```
ARG IMAGE
FROM ${IMAGE}

RUN sudo apt-get update \
  && sudo echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/rundeck/rundeck-deb /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list \
  && sudo curl "https://bintray.com/user/downloadSubjectPublicKey?username=bintray" > /tmp/bintray.gpg.key \
  && sudo apt-key add - < /tmp/bintray.gpg.key \
  && sudo apt-get -y install apt-transport-https  \
  && sudo apt-get -y update \
  && sudo apt-get -y install rundeck-cli

ENV RD_AUTH_PROMPT false
# or your defined host
ENV RD_URL http://localhost:4440
ENV RD_USER admin
ENV RD_PASSWORD admin
```

To create  all environment do: `docker-compose up`

Enter to your container with: `docker exec -it your_rundeck_container bash`

And test RD-CLI doing: `rd run -j YourJobName -p YourProjectName`

You can see the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCDVb.jpg) and execution on [GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGsHR.jpg).

[Here](https://github.com/rundeck/docker-zoo) you have a lot of examples to do anything with Rundeck and Docker.